# decode TFRecord fail. Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\257\

Tags: image, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tfrecord

I encoded some images to TFRecords as an example and then try to decode them. However, there is a bug during the decode process and I really cannot fix it.

InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\257\222\244\257\222\244\260\223\245\260\223\245\262\225\247\263'
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

encode:
    def _bytes_feature(value):
      """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
      return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

```
def _float_feature(value):
  """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
  return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
  """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

src_path = r"E:\data\example"
record_path = r"E:\data\data"
sum_per_file = 4
num = 0
key = 3

for img_name in os.listdir(src_path):
    recordFileName = "trainPrecipitate.tfrecords"
    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(record_path + recordFileName)
    img_path = os.path.join(src_path, img_name)
    img = Image.open(img_path, "r")
    height = np.array(img).shape[0]
    width = np.array(img).shape[1]
    img_raw = img.tobytes()
    example = tf.train.Example(features = tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/encoded': _bytes_feature(img_raw),
        'image/class/label': _int64_feature(key),
        'image/height': _int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': _int64_feature(width)
    }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

decode:
    import IPython.display as display

```
train_files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(r"E:\data\datatrainPrecipitate.tfrecords")
train_files = train_files.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)

def decode_example(example_proto):
    image_feature_description = {
    'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/class/label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=3),
    'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
}
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)
    height = tf.cast(parsed_features['image/height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(parsed_features['image/width'], tf.int32)
    label = tf.cast(parsed_features['image/class/label'], tf.int32)
    image_buffer = parsed_features['image/encoded']
    image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    return image, label

def processed_dataset(dataset):
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(1)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
#     print(dataset)
    return dataset

train_dataset = train_files.map(decode_example)
# train_dataset = processed_dataset(train_dataset)
print(train_dataset)
for (image, label) in train_dataset:
    print(repr(image))
```

InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\257\222\244\257\222\244\260\223\245\260\223\245\262\225\247\263'
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]

Answer (score 0):

I can use tf.io.decode_raw() to decode the TFRecords and then use tf.reshape() to get the original image. While still don't know when to use tf.io.decode_raw() and when to use tf.io.decode_jpeg().